# Solution to the PDE $\partial_r f(r,\theta) + \partial_\theta f(r,\theta) g(f(r,\theta), f(r, 0)) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am interested in solving the following PDE for a fixed function $g$: $$\partial_r f(r,\theta) + \partial_\theta f(r,\theta)\ g\left(f\left(r,\theta\right), f\left(r, 0\right)\right) = 0$$

The nonstandard bit here is dependence of $g$ on $f(r,0)$, which makes this PDE nonlocal. If we fix a boundary condition for $f$ evaluated at $\theta=0$, then we can treat $g$ as a local function of $f$ and solve using standard methods.

However, I am interested in solving this equation with a boundary condition for $f$ evaluated at some $r=r_0$.  Since the equation is first-order in $r$, a unique solution should exist.

Is there any standard method for solving such a PDE? I would also be interested in any way of writing the PDE without the dependence on $f(r,0)$, perhaps as a second-order equation.

In case it is important, the function $g$ I am interested in is $$g\left(f\left(r,\theta\right),f\left(r,0\right)\right)=\left(f\left(r,0\right)\right)^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{f(r,0)}{f(r,\theta)}\right)^{2}-1\right)^{-1/2}$$

Also, here are two particular solutions that I am aware of:
$$f(r,\theta) = r \cos \theta$$
$$f(r,\theta) = \frac{\tanh(r) \cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-(\tanh(r) \cos\theta)^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following is true.
$$
f^{(1,0)}(r,\theta) = \partial_r f
$$
then using $f(r,\theta) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ yeilds
$$
R'\Theta + R\dot{\Theta}\frac{1}{R\Theta_0}\left[\left(\frac{R(r)\Theta_0}{R(r)\Theta(\theta)}\right)^2-1\right]^{-1/2} = \\
R'\Theta + \dot{\Theta}\frac{1}{\Theta_0}\left[\left(\frac{\Theta_0}{\Theta(\theta)}\right)^2-1\right]^{-1/2} = \\
R'\Theta + \frac{\dot{\Theta}}{\Theta_0}\left[\left(\frac{\Theta_0}{\Theta}\right)^2-1\right]^{-1/2}
$$
thus we will end up at
$$
R' + \frac{\dot{\Theta}}{\Theta}\frac{1}{\Theta_0}\left(\frac{\Theta_0}{\Theta}\right)^{-1}\left[1-\left(\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_0}\right)\right]^{-1/2} =\\
R' + \dot{\Theta}\frac{1}{\Theta_0^2}\left[1-\left(\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_0}\right)^2\right]^{-1/2} = 0
$$
thus
$$
\dot{\Theta}\frac{1}{\Theta_0^2}\left[1-\left(\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_0}\right)^2\right]^{-1/2}=-R'=\lambda^2
$$
thus the integrals are
$$
R' = -\lambda^2\implies R = -\lambda^2r + C_1\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_0}\right)^2}}\dot{\Theta} = \Theta_0^2\lambda^2
$$
the last integral is easily evaluated
$$
\arcsin\left(\frac{\Theta}{\Theta_0}\right) = \Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2
$$
thus
$$
\Theta(\theta) = \Theta_0 \sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right) 
$$
thus the solution is
$$
f(r,\theta) = -\Theta_0 \sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)\left(\lambda^2r - C_1\right)
$$

lets try it out
$$
-g(r,\theta) = \frac{1}{\Theta_0(\lambda^2r - C_1)}\left[\left(\frac{-\Theta_0 \sin\left(C_2\right)\left(\lambda^2r - C_1\right)}{-\Theta_0 \sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)\left(\lambda^2r - C_1\right)}\right)^2 - 1\right]^{-1/2}=\\
\frac{1}{\Theta_0(\lambda^2r - C_1)}\left[\left(\frac{\sin\left(C_2\right)}{\sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}\right)^2 - 1\right]^{-1/2}=\\
\frac{1}{\Theta_0(\lambda^2r - C_1)}\left[1-\left(\frac{\sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}{\sin(C_2)}\right)^2 \right]^{-1/2}\frac{\sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}{\sin(C_2)}
$$
here is where I make an assumption to make it work
$$
\sin(C_2) = 1
$$
rightly or wrongly..that's your decision.

$$
g(r,\theta) = -\frac{1}{\Theta_0(\lambda^2r - C_1)}\frac{\sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}{\cos\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}
$$
then
$$
-\Theta_0 \sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)\left(\lambda^2\right) +\left[-\Theta_0^2\lambda^2 \cos\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)\left(\lambda^2r - C_1\right)\right]\left[-\frac{1}{\Theta_0(\lambda^2r - C_1)}\frac{\sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}{\cos\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}\right] \tag{*}
$$
now
$$
\left[-\Theta_0^2\lambda^2 \cos\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)\left(\lambda^2r - C_1\right)\right]\left[-\frac{1}{\Theta_0(\lambda^2r - C_1)}\frac{\sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}{\cos\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)}\right] = \Theta_0\lambda^2 \sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right)\tag{**}
$$
which placing Eq.  (**) into Eq.(*)
$$
-\lambda^2\Theta_0 \sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right) + \Theta_0\lambda^2 \sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + C_2\right) = 0
$$
which is the result we want so the solution with condition that $C_2 = \sin^{-1}(1)$ we can obtain
$$
f(r,\theta) =  -\Theta_0 \sin\left(\Theta_0\lambda^2\theta + \sin^{-1}(1)\right)\left(\lambda^2r - C_1\right)
$$
so this analysis is subject to the condition on $C_2$ which is not usual as you require B.C/I.C to prescribe these and not the model itself.

Comment: This is really great, thanks!  I think the condition on $C_2$ is fine, since it just enforces the boundary condition for $\Theta_0$.  The issue for me now is that I want to fix a boundary condition for all $\theta$ at fixed $r$, i.e. $f(r_0, \theta) = h(\theta)$ for some arbitrary function $h$. This solution requires a very specific form for $h$.  I am hopeful that your approach will help me find this general solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. I think this is very interesting. So where does the pde come from? Physics, chemistry? As you can see that I have not allowed for boundary conditions. Just manipulation really :).

Comment: It comes from a Physics problem, but it's really geometry – We are trying to construct a Riemannian manifold given only lengths of boundary-to-boundary geodesics (subject to a few conditions).  The boundary condition $f(r_0, \theta)$ comes from these lengths.

Comment: Whilst i did physics this is an area I have done well to stay away from ;)!! Good luck with the research.